# Typescript: Work around type definition error for javascript builtin

Tags: types, typescript

I want to use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) in typescript.  Unfortunately, the [generated typescript definition files](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L10208) doesn't support a FormData constructor with a Form Element as detailed in  [Typescript Issue #1074](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1074).

I have the following code:

```
var formEl = <HTMLFormElement> document.getElementById("myForm");
var formData = new FormData(formEl);
```

The code gives the following error because the [generated definition](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L10208) is wrong:

> error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

I want to use the following declaration:

```
declare var FormData: {
    prototype: FormData;
    new (form?: HTMLFormElement): FormData;
}
```

But, if I include that type definition, I get this error:

> error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'FormData' must be of type '{ new (): FormData; prototype: FormData; }', but here has type '{ new (form?: HTMLFormElement): FormData; prototype: FormData; }'.

How can I work around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I work around this issue?

## Potential 1:

Send a PR.

## Potential 2:

Update the shipped `lib.d.ts` in place:

```
declare var FormData: {
    prototype: FormData;
    new (form?: HTMLFormElement): FormData;
}
```

## Potential 3:

Copy and customize `lib.d.ts` and compile with `--noLib` and manually reference your custom `lib.d.ts`.

## Potential 4:

Bypass the type-checker

```
var formEl = <HTMLFormElement> document.getElementById("myForm");
var formData = new window['FormData'](formEl);
```

Comment: Bummer, I was hoping I could just include the new declaration.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the VS2017 typescript libraries (which may have been fixed in the April 2017 update).  You can around the error you noted by turning off the LanguageService in Tools|Options|Text Editor|JavaScript/TypeScript|LanguageService
Just uncheck the "Enable the new JavaScript language service." checkbox.

More details of the issue are on
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25310/unload-projects-hangs-on-close-solution.html

Answer (score 0):

There's already a [bug on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1074). It's targeted for fixing in TypeScript 1.6.

Until then, this is a simple workaround in TypeScript:

```
var formEl = <HTMLFormElement> document.getElementById("myForm");
var formData = <FormData> new (<any> FormData) (formEl);
```

And the generated javascript, just what you wanted:

```
var formData = new FormData(formEl);
```

This should keep working even after they fix the lib.d.ts issue.